# Python: SciPy.interpolate PiecewisePolynomial

Tags: python, scipy

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import PiecewisePolynomial

xi = np.array([1,10])
yi = np.array([10,1])

p = PiecewisePolynomial(xi,yi)
```

Does not yield a linear interpolation of the two points but

```
ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero
```

What's wrong there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your `yi` with

```
yi = np.array([[10], [1]])
```

PiecewisePolynomial requires `y` array to be an `array-like` or a `list-of-array` structure. Each element of `y` can be a function value for `x` and its subsequent derivatives. Above change to `y` creates the correct linear interpolation

```
p = PiecewisePolynomial(xi,yi)
p.__call__([5.])
>> array([6.])
p.__call__([2.])
>> array([9.])
```